# What's the difference between socket.to(id) and socket.broadcast.to(id)?

Tags: socket.io

I'm write an application using socket.io.

I'm confused by the official document about socket.broadcast.
From my testing, the below code has the same effect:

```
socket.to(id).emit('some event')

socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('some event')
```

What's does broadcast do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`broadcast` sets a flag in socket,

```
Socket.prototype.__defineGetter__('broadcast', function () {
  this.flags.broadcast = true;
  return this;
});
```

which tells the manager to [omit current socket from broadcasting](http://socket.io/docs/#broadcasting-messages)

```
Socket.prototype.packet = function (packet) {
  if (this.flags.broadcast) {
    this.log.debug('broadcasting packet');
    this.namespace.in(this.flags.room).except(this.id).packet(packet);
  } else {
...
```

Thus `socket.broadcast.to(room)` will have the following effect: client that is connected to the `socket` will not receive the message. Whereas when `socket.to(room)` all room's clients will receive the message including the one who is connected to `socket`.

I've just verified this for socket v0.9 but I doubt these mechanics are different for v1.+

Comment: Kirill, thanks for your answer, but I tried `socket.to(room_id)`, `room_id` is **NOT** another socket's id,  it's the id of a **room**. In fact, It behaves the same as `socket.broadcast.to(room_id)`. The other sockets in that room will be notified with the event. Then this makes `socket.broadcast` useless, `socket.to` can do everything `socket.broadcast` do.

Comment: You're right. I missed the point. But there definitely is a difference. I have it used in one of my projects. I've tested the two ways. See updated answer

Comment: great, thanks for the detailed answer.  It even clear the another doubt I have is: when in node-inspector debug, I see that `broadcast` property's value is undefined, so I was wondering why `socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('some event')` can even work. Now I know all the magic is in the getter method of `broadcast` property.  But anyway, I'm using 1.3.5 version, `socket.to(roomid)` also excludes the sender socket.

Comment: @Aaron, so according to your results in v1.3.5 there is no difference whether to use `broadcast` when sending to a room?

Comment: To broadcast everyone in a room including the sender, we can use `io.sockets.to(roomid).emit`

Comment: Then what's the use-case for `broadcast` in 1.3.5? I expect one otherwise they would deprecate it...

Comment: don't know... the documentation is not clear. Only by doing test ourselves can figure out the differences.

Comment: I'm on confusing about this. As Aaron Shen said, socket.to(socketid or room) does exactly same with socket.broadcast.to(socketid or room) as it exclude the sender. Are there anyway to send to multiple socket id within 1 command like this socket.to ([socketid1, socketid2, socketid3]) ? I've tried this but it not work. But it's weird when the array has 1 item, it normally work so socket.to(id) is same with socket.to([id]). But if an array 2 items or above it doesn't work